# How can I remove particular tools in TradingView widget JS?

Tags: charts, widget, tradingview-api

The current TradingView widget loaded very slowly in the website.
Except that it has a lot of unnecessary functions for users, which I need to remove from the widget.

How can I remove this tools from tradingview widget? The code is below:

```
new TradingView.widget({
    symbol: 'Bitfinex:ETHUSD',
    interval: '5',
    theme: 'Dark',
    style: '1',
    container_id: "tv_chart_container",
    library_path: "/charting_library/",
    locale: lang,
    width: '100%',
    height: '618px',
    hide_top_toolbar: false,
    left_toolbar: true,
    hide_side_toolbar: false,
    allow_symbol_change: false,
    hideideas: false,
    debug: false,
    chartsStorageUrl: 'https://saveload.tradingview.com',
    chartsStorageApiVersion: '1.1',
    clientId: 'tradingview.com',
    userId: 'public_user_id',
    disabled_features: [
        'use_localstorage_for_settings',
    ],
    preset: 'mobile',
    'studies': [
        'Volume@tv-basicstudies'
    ]
})
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how can I pass the chart my own symbols and my own trading data?

Comment: @Afsanefda hmmm, no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researches and conversation with TradingView support team I has been notified that ITS NOT POSSIBLE yet :)

Comment: Is it possible now?

Comment: Im not sure, you need to check

Comment: It is possible now. I will create an answer for you.

Answer (score 9):

enabled_features: ["hide_left_toolbar_by_default"]

Comment: left_toolbar is the one

Answer (score 2):

As per the TradingView docs, you need to provide this value to the widgetOptions:

```
disabled_features: ['left_toolbar'],
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide certain drawing tools in the left toolbar you would include a `drawings_access` object in your widget constructor.

https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Widget-Constructor#drawings_access

(link will only be available if you have access to the Trading View Charting Library repo)

Example of removing the Brush and Rectangle tools:

```
// inside widget constructor
drawings_access: {
    type: "black",
    tools: [
        {
            name: "Brush"
        },
        {
            name: "Rectangle"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I tried but it doesnt solve the problem